# Budget stand for an IBC (1m or higher)

Tags: water, gardening

I have some IBC's to be used for rainwater storage - but I want to elevate them so I can water directly from them with a hose.

Has anyone got any cunning/clever ideas on how to elevate them at minimum cost? They are in aluminium frames designed to be lifted by forklift, so have structure to attach to.

I am reasonably handy with wood.

Comment: Presumably they fit on pallets? Maybe stack a few of those? You can often find them free/cheap.

Comment: Cheers @LShaver - it takes a lot of pallets to get that high, and in practice they aren't that freely available around here -- I have been looking to make stands out of wood from pallets as I have a few, but safety is an issue so I don't want to under-engineer it.

Comment: Pallets on an even, stony surface should suffice. Maybe protect the pallets from weather by skirting them with some plastic sheet. Or place the IBCs on top of a small mound of dirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pallets work in terms of strength, but in moist climates/conditions they don't last long (source: experience with central/western German climate)
- Over here, it's reasonably easy to get smallish amounts of bricks (e.g. sandlime or concrete blocks) via small-ads. If it's not time-critical (can wait until the stones happen to be available nearby), I'd thus tend to put up walls if this is meant to last. Then screw the IBC frames on top for added stability. This gives some outdoor shelf/storage space as well.

---

We have tanks on low side of our grounds, so rain flows into them on its own (and with sufficient pipe diameter and incline to make it flow fast enough for a downpour). I'm considering to put up a tank at the high side (which is above the level of the roof gutter), and pump water in there as needed.